# Why is my scikit learn HashingVectorizor giving me floats with binary = True set?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I'm trying to use scikit-learn's Bernoulli Naive Bayes classifier.  I had the classifier working fine on a small data set using CountVectorizor, but ran into trouble when I tried to use HashingVectorizor for working with a larger data set.  Holding all other parameters (training documents, test documents, classifier & feature extractor settings) constant and just switching from CountVectorizor to HashingVectorizor caused my classifier to always spit out the same label for all documents.

I wrote the following script to investigate what would be different between the two feature extractors:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer, CountVectorizer

cv = CountVectorizer(binary=True, decode_error='ignore')
h = HashingVectorizer(binary=True, decode_error='ignore')

with open('moby_dick.txt') as fp:
    doc = fp.read()

cv_result = cv.fit_transform([doc])
h_result = h.transform([doc])

print cv_result
print repr(cv_result)
print h_result
print repr(h_result)
```

(where 'moby_dick.txt' is the project gutenberg copy of moby dick)

The (condensed) results:

```
  (0, 17319)    1
  (0, 17320)    1
  (0, 17321)    1
<1x17322 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 17322 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

  (0, 1048456)  0.00763203138591
  (0, 1048503)  0.00763203138591
  (0, 1048519)  0.00763203138591
<1x1048576 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 17168 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

As you can see, the CountVectorizor, in binary mode, returns integer 1 for the value of every feature(we only expect to see 1 since there's only one document); the HashVectorizor on the other hand is returning floats (all the same, but different documents produce a different value).  I suspect my issues stem from passing these floats onto BernoulliNB.

Ideally, I would like a way to get the same binary format data from HashingVectorizor as I get from CountVectorizor; failing that, I could use the BernoulliNB binarize parameter if I knew a sane threshold to set for this data, but I am not clear on what those floats represent (they're clearly not token counts, as they're all the same and less than 1).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the default settings, `HashingVectorizer` normalizes your feature vectors to unit Euclidean length:

```
>>> text = "foo bar baz quux bla"
>>> X = HashingVectorizer(n_features=8).transform([text])
>>> X.toarray()
array([[-0.57735027,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.57735027,
         0.        , -0.57735027,  0.        ]])
>>> scipy.linalg.norm(np.abs(X.toarray()))
1.0
```

Setting `binary=True` only postpones this normalization until after binarizing the features, i.e. setting all the non-zero ones to one. You also have to set `norm=None` to turn it off:

```
>>> X = HashingVectorizer(n_features=8, binary=True).transform([text])
>>> X.toarray()
array([[ 0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ]])
>>> scipy.linalg.norm(X.toarray())
1.0
>>> X = HashingVectorizer(n_features=8, binary=True, norm=None).transform([text])
>>> X.toarray()
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.]])
```

This is also why it's returning `float` arrays: normalization requires them. While the vectorizer could be rigged to return another dtype, that would require conversion inside the `transform` method and probably one *back* to float in the next estimator.

Comment: Why is there a minus sign?

Comment: @YoshuaJooBin

[HashingVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html):  

> `alternate_sign`, bool, default=True  
> When True, an alternating sign is added to the features as to approximately conserve the inner product in the hashed space even for small `n_features`. This approach is similar to sparse random projection.

Answer (score 0):

To replace `CountVectorizer(binary=True)` by `HashingVectorizer` the proper parameters are: `norm=None` (default "l2"), `alternate_sign=False` (default True) and `binary=True` (default False).

However, if you require the output with the same `dtype` as from `CountVectorizer` you can specify `dtype="int64"` (default "float64").

Furthermore, `dtype="uint8"` is the optimal dtype when binary=`True` and will save you a lot of memory:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer, CountVectorizer
>>> 
>>> cv = CountVectorizer(binary=True)
>>> hv = HashingVectorizer(norm=None, alternate_sign=False, binary=True, dtype='uint8')
>>> 
>>> doc = "one two three two one"
>>> cv_result = cv.fit_transform([doc])
>>> hv_result = hv.transform([doc])
>>> 
>>> print(repr(cv_result))
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> print(cv_result)
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 2)    1
  (0, 1)    1
>>> print(f'used: {(cv_result.data.nbytes + cv_result.indptr.nbytes + cv_result.indices.nbytes)} bytes\n')
used: 44 bytes

>>> 
>>> print(repr(hv_result))
<1x1048576 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.uint8'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> print(hv_result)
  (0, 824960)   1
  (0, 884299)   1
  (0, 948532)   1
>>> print(f'used: {(hv_result.data.nbytes + hv_result.indptr.nbytes + hv_result.indices.nbytes)} bytes')
used: 23 bytes
```